# Hajj/Umrah from Bank Salary

Tags: sharia

Assalam O Alaikum,

Can me and my family perform hajj/umrah from the money which I earned from Bank job?

Regards,
SAM

Answer (score 2):

If the services that you rendered for the bank didn't directly involve anything that is haram, e.g. riba, then your earning/salary is halal and you can perform hajj with the money of that salary.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform haj/umrah from the salary that is earned from Halal ways and is earnings of your hardwork.

If there is anything haram involved, then that money is not valid for hajj and you should not do so.

It is a simple thing to know brother. You should earn halal, and should perform Islamic celebrations by that halal earning. Haram earning itself is not allowed in Islam.